# Events of correlated jointly Gaussian distributions

Tags: statistics, random-variables, normal-distribution, random-functions

Suppose you have $X,Y\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ jointly Gaussian distributed with correlation coefficient $\rho$. I am looking for a convenient formula of the following expression:
$$\mathbb{P}(\{|X|>1\}\cap\{|Y|>1\}).$$
In particular, I am interested in the limit $\rho\rightarrow0$. If $\rho=0$, we know that
$$\mathbb{P}(\{|X|>1\}\cap\{|Y|>1\})=\mathbb{P}(\{|X|>1\})\cdot\mathbb{P}(\{|Y|>1\})=\mathbb{P}(\{|X|>1\})^2$$
which can be expressed using the error function. But as of right now, I am not even able to show this convergence, because the integrals involved in calculating the left hand side for $\rho>0$ are too unwieldy.

It would be great if I could find a rate of convergence of
$$\mathbb{P}(\{|X|>1\}\cap\{|Y|>1\})-\mathbb{P}(\{|X|>1\})^2\xrightarrow{\rho\rightarrow 0} 0$$

Thanks!

Comment: A simple application of DCT proves this convergence. There is no need to evaluate any integral.

Comment: Yes, nice solution! Unfortunately my problem goes further. I need some statement about the convergence speed. Suppose I set $\rho=\exp(-n)$ and want to evaluate the distance to the limit for each choice of $n$. Does that distance also decay exponentially?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a rate of convergence that is sufficient to me. It is the case that
$$F(\rho):=\mathbb{P}(\{|X|>1\}\cap\{|Y|>1\})-\mathbb{P}(\{|X|>1\})^2\leq L|\rho|$$
for some constant $L>0$. My proof of this is quite lengthy but it comes down to writing the function as
\begin{equation*}
   F(\rho)=\int_{M}f_{0,\Sigma_\rho}(x_1,x_2)-f_{0,\Sigma_0}(x_1,x_2)d(x_1,x_2)
  \end{equation*}

on $I:=[-\rho_0,\rho_0]$, $\rho_0<1$. Here, $f_{0,\Sigma_\rho}$ is the two dimensional Gaussian pdf with mean (0,0) and covariance matrix
\begin{equation*}
   \Sigma_\rho=\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & \rho\\
    \rho & 1
   \end{pmatrix}
  \end{equation*}
If we can show that $F$ is continuously differentiable with bounded derivative on $I$, we are done and $L$ is just that bound. The lengthy part is showing that for all $\rho\in I$, the functions $\partial_\rho f_{0,\Sigma_\rho}$ are uniformly bounded by an integrable function $g:\mathbb R^2\rightarrow\mathbb R_+$ so that we may exchange differentiation and integral in $\partial_\rho F(\rho)$.

AM, Berlin